# Change + symbol to operate something else?

Tags: python, symbols, addition

How to change symbol + (button in keyboard) in python to operate your custom def rather than default addition ?

Comment: Out of interest, what is it you intend for the + symbol to do?

Comment: fuzzy arithmetics, ex. 5 + 2  >> 7 but in fuzzy arithemetics is 7 with a function following number 7.

Comment: As no one seems to have mentioned it yet, what you want to do is called operator overloading [and this is a good reference](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR26/PQR2.6.html#SpecialMethods) to know which operators you can overload.

Comment: plz someone from the answers below indicate me, where my BUTTON + (pressing shift and +) can be changed to my custom def. I know it might my sound weird, but i just need to change a BUTTON keyboard to operate my custon def then i script in python (2.7.3).

Comment: @StavrosAnastasiadis: You're going to have to add more info. Where are you typing this?

Comment: @Blender, as i write in my previous comment, i just want after import myscript.py, to be able not to type myscript.mydef(a,b) but BUTTON + (pressing shift and +) to be able to make a + b ( myscript.mydef(a,b)).

Comment: @StavrosAnastasiadis: `__add__` and `__radd__` are implemented by `a` and `b`. You can't globally override them for *every* object unless you monkey patch *every* type at the time of import, which isn't fool-proof and is bound to break things. Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement one or more of the following methods on your class:

- `__add__` - handles the case when you have `(your object) + (some other object)`
- `__radd__` - handles the case when you have `(some other object) + (your object)` and the other object doesn't know how to do the addition.
- `__iadd__` - handles `(your object) += (some object)`. You don't necessarily need to implement this, as Python will call `__add__` if you don't.

There are corresponding "magic" methods for other operations, mathematical and otherwise, [see here](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Answer (score 2):

Numeric operations on classes are delegated to [various methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). Simply implement them on your class to perform the desired operation.

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __add__(self, other):
     ...
```

Note that you cannot change the behavior of the standard operators when the operand or both operands are existing types.